# How to Debug SSL Logs in Amazon CloudWatch Logs

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

How to Debug SSL Connection in Amazon CloudWatch (Lambda function)?

It is working in normal java project using `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl")` but not working in Amazon CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: posting the error messages you see and sections of your code might help you get an answer

Comment: @caffreyd error message : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  while calling remote server i need to pass certificate and password while handshaking i am getting error out of 100 request 90 times no error only 10 times i am getting

Comment: so if debug the ssl connection i can easily find out what is the issue so i tried in standalone java i can able to get ssl debug logs but not able to print in aws cloudwatch logs

Comment: finally i found a solution hoping it helpful for others in lambda Environment Variables you need to add Key: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS            value : -Djavax.net.debug = ssl  ref : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html